# Autocomplete C# for emacs

Tags: c#, emacs, autocomplete, intellisense

Although, I used Ubuntu for C++ programming, I have recently started programming in C# in Ubuntu. Earlier, I used Microsoft Visual Studio for that. I am using Emacs as my text editor.

I am really missing the IntelliSense feature of Visual Studio. How can I get that feature in Emacs? or can I get that feature in Emacs ?

I have used auto complete mode in Emacs, but it is not working in C#.

Comment: The googles suggest [C# autocompletion in Emacs](http://bbbscarter.wordpress.com/2013/08/17/c-autocompletion-in-emacs/).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [Monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com)? i am also trying find a IDE to code in c#. for now, i am using mono deveop. it's not feature full as visual studio, but it has a limited auto complete feature based on .net frame work 4.0.

I didn't try it in linux though. i am using it in mac. but, it would worth a trial if you have time.

Comment: I have tried monodevelop but simply love emacs and the working in terminal on ubuntu that I don't want to use and IDE.

Comment: best of luck.. i will also try emac then. :) have a great day